# Correct camlQuery to retrieve list item value via JavaScript and setting that value in another list

Tags: list, javascript, caml, xml

I have two lists: `Catalog` and `Position`.

I want to retrieve the value of a list item in `Catalog`and use it for the value of a list item in `Position`.

To get the list items' value `Title`, I used

```
// Get values from Catalogue list
function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    catalogueList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Catalog');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); // initiate the query object
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' +
        '<Value Type=\'Text\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    itemColl = catalogueList.getItems(camlQuery);
    // returns the item collection based on the query
    context.load(itemColl);
    context.executeQueryAsync(retrieveListItemsSuccess, retrieveListItemsFail);
}

function retrieveListItemsSuccess() {
    var listItemEnumerator = itemColl.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var listDetails = oListItem.get_item('Title') ;
        console.log("listDetails: " + listDetails);
    }

}
// This function is executed if the above call fails
function retrieveListItemsFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get list items. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

This will return different title strings, such as "Title1", "Title2" etc.

Using the following code, I want to set the value I got in the `Position` list:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Position');
var item = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

var oListItem = oList.addItem(item);
oListItem.set_item('Title', listDetails);
```

The problem I have is that I don't know what to change in `camlQuery.set_viewXML`, so that it returns the `Title` if the list item `ID` has a certain value (f.ex. 4). Right now it just returns the first 10 elements, but I want to get the value of a specific list item. How can one achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>{PUT YOUR LOOKUP ITEM ID HERE WITHOUT THESE CURLY BRACES}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>`